# Shell script to run jar of any version

Tags: java, bash

How can I make a `shell` `script` that will execute a `jar` file, regardless of its version?

Say I have a file:

> my-jar-file-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar

I want a shell script that will do something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
java -some -other -options -jar my-jar-file-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar
```

But it should execute any version of it, so

1. my-jar-file-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar
2. my-jar-file-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar
3. my-jar-file-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar

should all be executed by the same script.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you should use soft links. ln -s my-jar-file-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar my-jar-file-1.0.1-executable.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If name of jar match pattern `my-jar-version.jar`:

```
java -jar `ls my-jar*.jar`
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also think the other way around, why not give a final name to jar, which will remain constant, and no script modifications will be required.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>myname</finalName>
    <configuration>
</plugin>
```

And if having the version number mandatory, you can write a script to pattern search for that particular jar. And run it accordingly.

I did a similar job using ant, but the goal was different, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a bash script:

```
for jarfile in my-jar-file-*-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar; do
    java -some -other -options -jar $jarfile
    echo "done for: $jarfile"
done
```